# How to get Database Name in a Logon Trigger using EVENTDATA()

Tags: t-sql, authentication, triggers

below the Database name is always blank

I am trying to get Database Name in a Logon Trigger using EVENTDATA() but its not working and it appears like the EVENTDATA() is not working at all, I am trying to block users who are using  excel to query the 'TestDB'. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong with this code.

CREATE TRIGGER tr_block_excel_users
ON ALL SERVER FOR LOGON
AS

declare @data XML
declare @DatabaseName as varchar(128)

SET @data = EVENTDATA();
set @DataBaseName = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)')

BEGIN
    IF (select @DatabaseName) = 'TestDB' and ORIGINAL_LOGIN() <> N'xx\xxxxxxxex' AND APP_NAME() LIKE '%Microsoft Office%'  OR APP_NAME() LIKE '%EXCEL%'
    ROLLBACK;
END

I expected the name of the database using EVENTDATA(), but getting a blank database name,

Comment: For an [EVENT_INSTANCE_LOGON](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2006/11/eventdata/events.xsd) there is no `DatabaseName`. It's an event on server level not on database level.

Comment: How do I  get the event at the database level?..Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Database Name in a Logon SQL Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56358826/how-to-get-database-name-in-a-logon-sql-trigger)

Comment: @Sam You have asked exactly the same question in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56358826/how-to-get-database-name-in-a-logon-sql-trigger/56359288#56359288 please avoid asking ONE question, multiple times

Comment: No, the sql is different for this trigger to get the answer that works,,

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just get the database and load it into the variable you can try:

```
 SET @DatabBaseName = SELECT DB_NAME()
```